# Python Forward Kinematics

Tags: ros, python, forward-kinematics, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I perform forward kinematics in python?

Can I use MoveItCommander to perform forward kinematics? I don't see analogous classes/functions as exist in the C++ kinematics API.

Similar questions have suggested using `pykdl_utils` instead, but I see that that package last existed in hydro. I also imagine that the package `python_orocos_kdl` has the functionality, but I'm having trouble finding useful documentation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280643/python-forward-kinematics/) by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2018-01-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://answers.ros.org/question/281272/get-forward-kinematics-wo-tf-service-call-from-urdf-joint-angles-kinetic-python/?answer=281455#post-id-281455

I was able to clone the https://github.com/gt-ros-pkg/hrl-kdl indigo-devel branch directly into my catkin_ws and use it for FK w/o any problems - so far.

```
from urdf_parser_py.urdf import URDF
from pykdl_utils.kdl_kinematics import KDLKinematics

# pykdl_utils setup
robot_urdf = URDF.from_xml_string(urdf_str)
kdl_kin = KDLKinematics(robot_urdf, base_link, end_link)

test_jt_angles = [0, 0, 0]
pose = kdl_kin.forward(test_jt_angles)
```

---

Thanks for the tip you gave me on my question. May still end up going down that route if I run into problems.

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1